# How do I post json data in scalaj?

Tags: json, scala, scalaj-http

I am using scalaj to make a Http post request

How can I pass  lat,long and radius as arguments in the postData field

```
val result = Http("http:xxxx/xxx/xxxxx").postData("""{"latitude":"39.6270025","longitude":"-90.1994042","radius":"0"}""").asString
```

Why is the string passed in """json""" such a manner?

Based on the docs it looks like the postData function takes only array of bytes and string as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is two questions at once. Let's start with the second one.

> Why is the string passed in """json""" such a manner?

Scala allows special syntax for multiline string literals (or strings containing newlines, quotation marks and so on). 
So you can do

```
val s = """Welcome home!
           How are you today?"""
```

Now back to the main question

> How can I pass lat, long and radius as arguments in the postData field?

I suppose you are in this situation:

```
val lat = "39.6270025"
val long = "-90.1994042"
```

And you want to pass that into the `postData` function, mixed with some other maybe fixed strings.

Well another feature Scala gives is so-called `string interpolation`.
Easy example

```
val name = "Mark" // output on the REPL would be: name: String = Mark
val greeting = s"Hello $name!" // output on the REPL would be: greeting: String = Hello Mark!
```

So in your case you could do the same

```
val result = Http("http:xxxx/xxx/xxxxx")
  .postData(s"""{"latitude":$lat,"longitude":$long,"radius":"0"}""")
  .asString
```